# Bootstrap ¿Cambiar color dropdown?

Tags: css, bootstrap

Buenas a todos.
Estoy tratando de cambiar el color del dropdown usando Bootstrap 3.

"Nombre_C" se ve en color blanco cuando tiene el mouse encima:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando se quita el mouse se ve en gris:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero cambiar es el color gris a naranja.

HTML:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="">WP</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#pedidos">PEDIDOS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#productos">MIS PRODUCTOS</a></li>

        <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user">
            </span>NOMBRE_C<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Mi Cuenta</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span>Cerrar Sesión</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
  .navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: #f4511e;
  z-index: 9999;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  line-height: 1.42857143 !important;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;

  .navbar li a, .navbar .navbar-brand {
  color: #fff !important;

  .navbar-nav li a:hover, .navbar-nav li.active a {
      color: #f4511e !important;
      background-color: #fff !important;

  .navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
      border-color: transparent;
      color: #fff !important;

.dropdown li a {
      color: #f4511e !important;
```

Comment: Con los estilos que pones no he conseguido reproducir tu problema. A mí no se me vuelve gris en ningún momento. Deberías poner un ejemplo completo, incluyendo css y html para poder reproducirlo.

Comment: Agregué código HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes sobrescribir el color por defecto de bootstrap con:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a.dropdown-toggle{
  background-color: #f4511e !important;
}
```

Algo así:

```css
.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: #f4511e;
  z-index: 9999;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  line-height: 1.42857143 !important;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
}
.navbar li a, .navbar .navbar-brand {
  color: #fff !important;
}
.navbar-nav li a:hover, .navbar-nav li.active a {
  color: #f4511e !important;
  background-color: #fff !important;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: transparent;
  color: #fff !important;
}
.dropdown li a {
  color: #f4511e !important;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a.dropdown-toggle{
  background-color: #f4511e !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="">WP</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#pedidos">PEDIDOS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#productos">MIS PRODUCTOS</a></li>

        <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user">
            </span>NOMBRE_C<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Mi Cuenta</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span>Cerrar Sesión</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```